Fatal error in launcher Unable to create process install package
while i try to install any packages in django i get this error
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\PCADI\backend\myVenv\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\data-collection\backend\myVenv\Scripts\pip.exe" install': Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable.
i solve this issue with the following command :
python -m pip
then install the package that you want like the following command i try to  install django-multiupload in my case :
python -m pip install django-multiupload
and it's installed
Successfully installed django-multiupload-0.6.1

I solved this issue with the following command:
python -m pip 

Then install the package that you want, like the following command. I try to install django-multiupload in my case:
python -m pip install django-multiupload

And it's installed successfully installed django-multiupload-0.6.1.
